# Does Job scheduler api work when app is killed?

Tags: android, service, android-jobscheduler

I am making an android app, and there is a scenario where I want to use background services to send GPS data to the server if the network is available.
I am planning to use JobSchdulerApi. I am curious to know if this will work when the app is killed from current tasks list or force stopped.

Any working sample link or code will help thanks in advance.

Comment: I would not expect `JobScheduler` jobs to survive a "Force Stop" from the Settings app. They should survive task removal, though there will be a few devices that tied a device-supplied task manager to "Force Stop"-style behavior.

Comment: Is there any difference if app is killed from task or from settings force stop?  @CommonsWare

Comment: @VikashKumarTiwari: This is what I covered in [the comment shown above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48063142/does-job-scheduler-api-work-when-app-is-killed?noredirect=1#comment83099116_48063142).

Comment: i have also the same issue. When application is alive then code running well but when i have killed the application the background execution not working.

Answer (score 2):

`JobSchedular` runs `JobService` after minimum 15 minutes. So if you set time less than 15 minutes, `JobSchedular` will ignore the time you have set. However if you have set time greater than 15 minutes suppose 18 minutes, `JobSchedular` will execute your job at 18 minutes or after 18 minutes but not before 18 minutes.

`JobSchedular` is not killed when app is killed(removed from recent tasks) but if you have set time less than 15 minutes, it will run job at 15 minutes or after 15 minutes but not before 15 minutes. `JobSchedular` is killed and android system will not execute `JobService` if app is `Force Stoped` from settings.